# NoClassDefFoundError Android with ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, noclassdeffounderror

I currently have an `ActionBarActivity` which always returns a `NoClassDefFoundError`. I've read that it might be a problem with the ADT but I cannot be sure, hence my question. I've imported the ActionBar sample from the Android samples under

`android-sdk\samples\android-14\ActionBarCompat`

I've labelled the ActionBarCompat project as a library under Project -> Properties but I'm still getting the error.

To reiterator:

```
public class SearchActivity extends ActionBarActivity { // Doesn't work, yields exception

public class SearchActivity extends Activity { // Works perfectly
```

Has anyone else experienced a similar error and perhaps found a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: `minSDKVersion=8`, `targetSDKVersion=14`.

My device runs Android 2.3.5 while my AVD runs Android 4.1. The program crashes on both with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using ActionBarSherlock instead and added a project reference under Project Properties as well as in the Build Path. Seems to have fixed all errors relating to my question.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html
The "Adding libraries with resources" section may help
since this is not in the most common v4 support library

include only android-support-v4.jar is not enough

Answer (score 0):

Just this morning, Google released Android 4.3. They also updated its support library that allows `ActionBar` to be implemented on lower versions. Just have to extend `ActionBarActivity`. See guidelines [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) and tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. I solved it getting the android-support-v7-appcompat.jar library.

See here http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#using-apis how to install it.

I recommend focus on "Adding libraries without resources" instead "Adding libraries with resources" for the sake of simplicity.

When you do it, don't forget to import the this library into your Activity Java source. You can do it declaring import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like so, when you add the library make sure it does not have the android-support-v4 along with it (in libs folder of the library un-check android dependencies and android-support-v4), that's in the case where your project already have the android-support-v4, that's why you can't find class `ActionBarActivity`

Answer (score 0):

[This Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat)
 may help you.
This library is located in the /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/ directory.
Include in eclipse and add as library. This will solve your problem.